# onItemClick display details page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, onclick

I am reading from a database into a listview using a custom cursor adapter. The listview shows some details of each entry in the database. When I click on a list item, I want to open a details page that shows the other details of that record that are not displayed in the listview. I can't figure it out.

I have attached the code snippets of the cursor creation and the adapter creation which are in MainActivity. I also have a separate customAdapter class and a class for the details page.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
        ...  
    }

    private void fillList() {
        ListView lv = getListView();

        Cursor c = db.getData();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductDetails.class);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**CustomCursorAdapter:**

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super(context, cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, parent, false);
            bindView(v, context, cursor);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView txtvw1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodcode_entry);
            txtvw1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.KEY_PRODCODE)));

            TextView txtvw2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodtype_entry);
            String ptype = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.KEY_PRODTYPE)));
            txtvw2.setText(ptype.substring(0, 1));

            TextView txtvw3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodcat_entry);
            String cat = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.PRODCAT)));
            txtvw3.setText(cat.substring(0, 2));

            TextView txtvw4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodcost_entry);
            float price = (cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.PRODPRICE)));
            txtvw4.setText(Float.toString(price));

            TextView txtvw5 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodSup_entry);
            txtvw5.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.SUPPLIER)));
        }
}
```

**ProdDetails**

```
public class ProductDetails extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.product_details);
    }
}
```

**db.getData() - from ProdDB**

```
public Cursor getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_PRODCODE,
                KEY_PRODNAME,
                KEY_PRODTYPE,
                KEY_PRODCAT,
                KEY_PRODPRICE,
                KEY_PRODRRP,
                KEY_PRODSUPPLIER,
                KEY_NOTES};

        return db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line:

```
Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductDetails.class);
```

pass also the id of the item:

```
k.putExtra("item_id", id);
// and start the activity
startActivity(k);
```

Then, from within the `ProductDeftails` activity, get the id again, query the database and retrieve its information:

```
// after setContentView...
long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("item_id", 0);
// use this variable to get the item again and populate your views
```

`getLongExtra` receives the key of the extra to retrieve plus a default value. It is always worthy to check the returned value against the default value to make sure the activity actually received something.

So, just remember this next time... creating an intent does not launch the activity it represents (you have to use either `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult` methods). Also, you can pass data to an activity that is going to be launched using the Intent's extras. It can be primitive types, Strings, String's ArrayLists, or Parcelables (single objects, array lists or arrays).

#### Details

To get the details of your product you can use something like this:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, 
        KEY_PRODCODE,
        KEY_PRODNAME,
        KEY_PRODTYPE,
        KEY_PRODCAT,
        KEY_PRODPRICE,
        KEY_PRODRRP,
        KEY_PRODSUPPLIER,
        KEY_NOTES};
return db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
```

You can put that inside a new method called `getDetails(long id)` (inside `ProdDB` class). Then, from within your activity you can do:

```
Cursor cursor = db.getDetails(id);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    // I assume you had already created the views in the ProductDetails activity
    txtvw1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.KEY_PRODCODE)))
} else {
    // something went wrong, do something
}
```

Comment: I've just implemented what you have put above and it starts the new activity. I just need to populate the fields now. Would you recommend the way that I have implemented it or is there a better way?

Comment: I recommend it this way, since it is faster. Though, as miNde suggests, if you create a class that represents each row in your table, it could be easier to understand (but it will be definitely slower). Also, if you follow his advise, read about Parcelable interface (I do not recommend Serializable one), since you will need it to do it in that way.

Comment: sorry to bother you but could you give me some pointers on using the `long id` to get the item from the database? I can't seem to work it out

Comment: Sure dude, no problem. Please edit your question and add the code of the db.getData() method.

Comment: Ok... I think that should help you. I have not compiled this, since I have no time.

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception when I click on one of the list items. I think it's how I've set up my activity. I'll try to work it out though thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class that will represent each data in your database, with the same fields. Then you will be able to use it in the adapter, and it will be way more easy to do what you want to because you will be able to retrieve in in the `onItemClick()` method using the integer `position`.
Then you just have to put it in the `Intent`, and in the second activity you can use it to display other infos (fields) that the `ListView` doesn't show.